# Remove quotation display from python string variable in HTML

Tags: python, html, html2pdf, quotation-marks

I have an html template where I am using a string variable generated from a pandas dataframe

My html
 Store:{{store_name}}

My string variable
store_name = df_bcu_temp['store description fr'].iloc[0]

When I look at my html I have :
**Store: "My store name"**

But I would like to see the same as above but WITHOUT QUOTATIONS
**Store: My store name**

Anybody can help ?

Comment: Try store_name = df_bcu_temp['store description fr'].iloc[0].str.replace('"', '')

Comment: this is not working when doing this I get this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'